# Pass two password to su commands

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am trying to run shell comment through PHP scripts.
I want to first su into a user then run a sudo command. I tried:

```
echo mypassword | (su -c "sudo reboot" user2)
```

It doesn't work because it requires two password and I only passed one password. I checked many other posts, the solution below doesn't work for me because I don't have the sudo password for the current user. I need to change the user a first then do a sudo. Can I get some help?

```
echo mypassword | sudo -s ...   Not work...
```

I know this is a bad practice. I just need it to restart server as the port 22 is closed accidentally. I can't ssh into the server to do any operations..

This is ONE time use to reboot the server from PHP side as I am not able to reach the admin to reboot the server right now. I fully understand the disadvantages... Please DO NOT suggest the disadvantages.

Answer (score 0):

Since it's an one time thing, try to use the following. It spawns a sudo environment (for the current user) in which `sudo reboot` is called.

```sh
#! /bin/bash

read -sp "pass? " pass

expect 2>&1 <<-EOF
        spawn sudo reboot
        expect "*: " { send "${pass}\r" }
        expect eof
        catch wait result
        exit [lindex \$result 3]
EOF

exit $?
```

You can call it as follows to automate stuff.

```sh
$ ./test.sh <<-EOF
notreallymypassword
EOF
```

Note: Although I think it works, I haven't tested it yet.