# Executing sudo command in bash script without displaying it

Tags: bash, ubuntu, output, sudo

I'm executing a command with sudo from bash script, and I'm wondering how to prevent sudo from displaying anything on the screen

```
echo "mypassword" |  sudo -S cp -u /scripts/.bashrc ~/ > /dev/null 2>&1
```

The result will be an output displaying: `[sudo] password for username:`

I want to hide that output..

**now, before the first comment;**
*This isn't the safest way, since you're entering your password into the script, but this is strictly internal servers.*

Comment: I tried your script on Ubuntu 18.04 and it does not display messages as you expect.

Comment: Duplicate. Check [this url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63142437/pass-two-password-to-su-commands/63143516#63143516).

Answer (score 2):

Run `sudo --help`, we can get answer from the parameter list:

```
-p, --prompt=prompt           use the specified password prompt
```

Then,

`echo "mypassword" | sudo -S --prompt="" cp -u /scripts/.bashrc ~/ > /dev/null 2>&1`

may do the trick.